# Sequelize js postgresql user defined types

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

One of the best feature of **Postgres** (as I see it) is the user-defined data types which let me define my data model in more readable and maintainable way.

Does anyone knows/have some advice how to use it with **SequelizeJs ORM**?

I can use associations, but then it will not be user-defined types and it will drag me back to old school sub-tables, which I want to avoid.

Comment: In general you get to choose ORMs *or* use of full database features.

Comment: @CraigRinger - generally I would agree, but in the case of Sequelize, which let you define the target db dialect, I think there is a way of defining it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide any type you want to the sequelize model definition by passing a string:

```
sequelize.define('name', {
  attr: 'SOME TYPE'
});
```

Sequelize does not support creating the custom type though (`CREATE TYPE`), so you'll have to write a custom query for that, and execute it directly on the db or using `sequelize.query`